# Original_purchase_date have different value for different transaction under the same original_transaction_id inside the latest_receipt_info

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

Inside apple receipt, there is a field called latest_receipt_info that contains all the latest transaction. The program that I am testing is using apple subscription.

My understanding is that for the same original_transaction_id, the original_purchase_date will be the same, because they are essentially referring to the same past transaction. Having said that, I got different original_purchase_date for different transaction under the same original_transaction_id. See the following:

```
original_purchase_date      "2021-05-29 09:58:24 Etc/GMT"
original_purchase_date_ms   "1622282304000"
original_purchase_date_pst  "2021-05-29 02:58:24 America/Los_Angeles"
original_transaction_id     "1000000790487038"
transaction_id              "1000000818740246"

original_purchase_date:     "2021-05-29 09:53:26 Etc/GMT"
original_purchase_date_ms   "1622282006000"
original_purchase_date_pst  "2021-05-29 02:53:26 America/Los_Angeles"
original_transaction_id     "1000000790487038"
transaction_id              "1000000818739843"

original_purchase_date      "2021-05-29 09:48:23 Etc/GMT"
original_purchase_date_ms   "1622281703000"
original_purchase_date_pst  "2021-05-29 02:48:23 America/Los_Angeles"
original_transaction_id     "1000000790487038"
transaction_id              "1000000818739088"
```

The above was extracted from unified_receipt.Latest_receipt_info in sandbox environment. This should be the same as responseBody.Latest_receipt_info in the verifyPayment.

Any idea why the original_purchase_date are not the same? Is this behavior expected to happen in production as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the `transaction_id` are not the same , just like  `original_purchase_date`.

for `original_transaction_id`, [apple said](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/original_transaction_id)

> `original_transaction_id` This value is identical to the `transaction_id` **except when the user restores a purchase or renews a subscription.**

> `original_transaction_id` This value has the same format as the transaction’s transactionIdentifier property; however, the values may not be the same

for `transaction_id` , [apple said](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/transaction_id)

> App Store generates a new value for transaction_id every time the subscription automatically renews or is restored on a new device.

Comment: Yes, correct. Nothing is wrong with the apple's guide that you mention. However, that does not answer my problem.

Comment: OK, I just map `date` issue to the `transaction_id ` issue,  which seems OK

Comment: The issue is I have multiple original transaction id for the same group subscription.
To my understanding, that should not have happened. Unless, there are other explanations.